# I want to add a class to a div after 2 seconds of the pageload

Tags: jquery, addclass, pageload, timedelay

I want to add a class to a div after 2 seconds of the pageload, please guide me how can I do it with jquery.

Comment: jQuery isn't needed here: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this.`$(window).ready(function(){})` will not call till your whole page will be ready and `setInterval()` will call after 2 sec.

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){ 
    $('div').addClass("test")
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<div>Class
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```